# mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple contradicting commands

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, mysql5

Any idea why I am seeing this error message? This script works fine on a ever so slightly older version of MySQL running on a different server with a similar config.

```
:: check/analyze/repair/optimize
@echo.
@echo Check Tables
%MYSQL_BIN%\mysqlcheck -u %MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PW% -v -1 -A -c
@echo.
@echo Repair Tables (medium)
%MYSQL_BIN%\mysqlcheck -u %MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PW% -v -1 -A -r -m
@echo.
@echo Analyze Tables
%MYSQL_BIN%\mysqlcheck -u %MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PW% -v -1 -A -a
@echo.
@echo Optimize Tables
%MYSQL_BIN%\mysqlcheck -u %MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PW% -v -1 -A -o
```

> Error: C:...\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqlcheck doesn't support multiple
>   contradicting commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least one of your switches is likely now mutually exclusive to another in one or more calls to `mysqlcheck`.

[Look each of them up](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) (`-v`, `-1,` `-A`, `-c`, `-r`, `-m`, `-a`, `-o`), figure out each of them does, and figure out how to break them out into separate calls to `mysqlcheck`, so they aren't contradicting each other.

As a hypothetical example, `-v` combined with `-r` might mean "set the clock back and set the clock forward" - an instruction that could arguably interpreted to be contradictory. If you want to do both operations, you must do them in two sequential calls to `mysqlcheck`, in the order you which require them to run.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Explained perfectly. I'll have a crack at this tomorrow and let you know when it's fixed ;-D

Answer (score 3):

As said before, the switches that you use are mutually exclusive: so you want to get rid of one option. Try this:

```
mysqlcheck -u %MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PW% --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases
```

If I'm not mistaken, you get the same with just one command.